# General Way of Calculating the third vertex isosceles triangles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

I am trying to find a general formula of computing the vertex $C$ of a **isosceles triangle**, in $2$-D Space. I have searched some examples, but I didn't find anything specific like the one below:

[image]

As I recall from Euclidean geometry, since the triangle is isosceles:

- $|AC| = |BC| = h \rightarrow |AC|^2 = |BC|^2 \rightarrow (A_x - C_x)^2 + (A_y - C_y)^2 = (B_x - C_x)^2 + (B_y - C_y)^2$
- If $M$ is the middle point, then $M = \left({A_x+B_x}{2},\dfrac{Ay+By}{2}\right)$
- Since line2 is vertical to line1, and line2: $y-M_y = l_2 \cdot (x-M_x)$, where $l_1*l_2=-1$ and $l_1, l_2$ and the gradients of line1, line2, respectively.
- $C$ is a point of line2.

The above equations form a system, which can be solved, but it seems to be complicated. Is there any more simple solution to finding the C point?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you interpret points as complex numbers then $A=x_A + i y_A$, $B=x_B + i y_B$, $B-A=x_B-x_A+i(y_B-y_A)$. $C-A=1/2 (1+i) (B-A)$ or $C-A = 1/2 (1-i) (B-A)$. Calculate $C-A$, then $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an approach that may help,

Say we have $A (x_1, y_1), B (x_2, y_2)$.
Find $c = |AB|$ and then $ \small |MC| = \cfrac{c}{2}$ when $\angle C = 90^\circ$. If not, then use $|MC| = \sqrt{h^2 - (c/2)^2}$.

Coordinates of $M$ is $ \displaystyle \left(x_0 = \frac{x_1 + x_2}{2}, y_0 = \frac{y_1 + y_2}{2}\right)$

If slope of $AB$ is $m$ then slope of $MC$ is $ \tan \theta = - \frac{1}{m}$.

Now using $\cos \theta = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+ \tan^2\theta}}, \sin \theta = \frac{\tan \theta}{\sqrt{1+ \tan^2\theta}}$

Coordinates of $C (x, y)$ is then given by,

$x = x_0 \pm |MC| \cos\theta, y = y_0 \pm |MC| \sin\theta$

Please note there are two different possible coordinates for $C$ - if we draw a square with one of the diagonals being $AB$, two ends of the other diagonal are two possible values of $C$.

Finally this translates to,

$ \left (x = x_0 \pm |MC| \cdot \frac{m}{ \sqrt{1+m^2}}, y = y_0 \mp |MC| \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+m^2}} \right)$

Comment: Thank you very much, this seems to be pretty explanatory

Comment: @LazyAnalyst I have taken example where $\angle C = 90^\circ$ as in your diagram. Do you have to do it for general case or when $\angle C = 90^\circ$? If in general, there is one additional step.

Comment: Yes, maybe You should state what happens if the angle of C isn't 90, in case someone else needs the answer

Comment: Sure, I made the edit.